# How can I make removal of Strikethrough text in Excel cells using XML parsing more robust?

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I have a complex spreadsheet with many cells of text containing random mixtures of normal text and text with strikethrough. Before I scan a cell for useful information, I have to remove the struck through text. I intially achieved this (with VBA) using the Characters object, but it was so slow as to be totally impractical, for business purposes. I was then kindly supplied with some code (on this site) that parses the XML encoding. This was 1000's of times faster, but it occassionally causes the following error:

"The parameter node is not a child of this node".

So far, it only happens in heavily loaded cells (1000's of characters), otherwise it works fine. I cannot see anything wrong in the code or the XML structure of the problem cells, although I am a total newbie to XML. Using the VBA debugger, I know the error is occurring when RemoveChild() is called, typically when it has already worked without error on a few struck through sections of a cell's text.

Is there a way I could make the following code more robust?

```vb
Public Sub ParseCellForItems(TargetCell As Excel.Range, ItemsInCell() As String)

Dim XMLDocObj As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim x As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim s As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

Dim CleanedCellText As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Call UnstrikeLineBreakCharsInCell(TargetCell)

Set XMLDocObj = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

'Add some namespaces.
XMLDocObj.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ss='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' " & _
    "xmlns:ht='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'"

'Load the cell data as XML into XMLDOcObj.
If XMLDocObj.LoadXML(TargetCell.Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet)) Then

    Set x = XMLDocObj.SelectSingleNode("//ss:Data") 'Cell content.

    If Not x Is Nothing Then

        Set s = x.SelectSingleNode("//ht:S") 'Struck through cell content.

        Do While Not s Is Nothing
            x.RemoveChild s
            Set s = x.SelectSingleNode("//ht:S")
        Loop

        CleanedCellText = XMLDocObj.Text

    'Parse CleanedCellText for useful information.'
    '...

    End If

End If

Set XMLDocObj = Nothing
'Presumably don't have to 'destroy' x and s as well, as they were pointing to elements of XMLObj.

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    Call RaiseError(Err.Number, Err.Source, "ParseCellForItems()", Err.Description, Erl)

End Sub

Public Sub UnstrikeLineBreakCharsInCell(TargetCell As Excel.Range)

Dim mc As MatchCollection
Dim RegExObj1 As RegExp
Dim Match As Variant

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Set RegExObj1 = New RegExp
RegExObj1.Global = True
RegExObj1.IgnoreCase = True
RegExObj1.Pattern = "\n" 'New line. Equivalent to vbNewLine.

Set mc = RegExObj1.Execute(TargetCell.Value)

For Each Match In mc
    TargetCell.Characters(Match.FirstIndex + 1, 1).Font.Strikethrough = False
Next Match

Set mc = Nothing
Set RegExObj1 = Nothing

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    Call RaiseError(Err.Number, Err.Source, "UnstrikeLineBreakCharsInCell()", Err.Description, Erl)

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `s.ParentNode.RemoveChild s`  (from https://p2p.wrox.com/xslt/8235-need-help-documentelement-removechild.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, as per Tim Williams' comment, making sure you're calling RemoveChild() from its immediate parent fixes the problem:

```
Set s = x.SelectSingleNode("//ht:S")
Do While Not s Is Nothing
    s.ParentNode.RemoveChild s
    Set s = x.SelectSingleNode("//ht:S")
Loop
```